# Inject custom labels into up metric

Tags: prometheus

It is not possible to use relabelling to add labels to the `up` metric. This is what I remember from the book by Brian Prometheus Up and Running.

I'm wondering then how to add there labels in the case that I don't control the Prometheus exporter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is true that [metric_relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs) doesn't apply to `up` because:

> Metric relabeling does not apply to automatically generated timeseries such as up.

But, if you really need it, [relabel_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) can add the label at configuration time (or using `labels` config of [static_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#static_config)):

```
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: job
    target_label:  my_new_label
    replacement:   label_value
```

Using `relabel_config` will add the label to all metrics ingested and if you need it to apply to `up` only, you can drop it at ingest time for all metrics:

```
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - regex: my_new_label
    action: labeldrop
```

Comment: As far as I understand the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config), the `action: labeldrop` ignores the `source_labels` and rather depends on `regex`, e.g.:

{
metric_relabel_configs:
  - regex: 'my_new_label'
    action: labeldrop
}